# Jboss CICS interaction for calling Mainframe using Resource Adapter

Tags: jboss

I have installed cicseci.rar on Jboss EAP 6.2. This resource adapter was downloaded from 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24008817#sthash.3k4M8smo.dpuf

However upon running my simple code i am getting this error -

```
  Exception Logged by: com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIInteraction

com.ibm.connector2.cics.CICSUserInputException: CTG9628E
InteractionSpec passed to execute() not of type ECIInteractionSpec
  at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIInteraction.execute(Unknown Source)
  at com.sample.checkstate.CICSPing.getIt(CICSPing.java:48)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispat
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Does anyone have any insights about this?

Comment: formate your code first

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and fter much research i found that the class ECIInteractionSpec is present in 2 jars - cicsj2ee.jar and ctgclient.jar . While ctgclient is a part of the deployment cicseci.rar , cicsj2ee is not. Hence at runtime, the jboss server tries to map ctgclient's class in ECIInteraction. This should be in fact taken from cicsj2ee.

The solution is to create a module and include all ctg related jars there -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.cics">
<resources>
<!-- Modules -->
<resource-root path="cicseci.jar" />
<resource-root path="cicsframe.jar"/>
<resource-root path="cicsj2ee.jar" />
<resource-root path="ctgclient.jar" />
<resource-root path="ctgserver.jar" />
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api" />
    <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

This should be given to the cics rar deployment as a module loader. You can include it as part of jboss-deployment-structure.xml or as a global module in standalone.xml.  This resolved the issue for me. Hope it helps you too.