# Jboss 7 CICS Connectivity Error InteractionSpec is not of type ECIInteractionSpec

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x, cics

I am migrating my JBoss 5 to jboss 7 using cics resource adaptor configuration for the cics.rar. the resources Adopters definition and configuration is done on standalone-full.xml file.  i am facing belolw error while hitting to application which is trying to connect to cics mainframe using cics rar.

Exception Logged
by:com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIInteraction
com.ibm.connector2.cics.CICSUserInputException: CTG9628E
InteractionSpec passed to execute() not of type ECIInteractionSpec at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIInteraction.execute(Unknown Source)

1.I have already checked the type passed in the execute method is of ECIInteractionSpec type only
2. Have followed the solution provided on below link but it did not work .

[Jboss CICS interaction for calling Mainframe using Resource Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305842/jboss-cics-interaction-for-calling-mainframe-using-resource-adapter)

Any suggestions much appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solution might apply to your situation. [Error executing CICS request while deploying app into IBM liberty Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786915/error-executing-cics-request-while-deploying-app-into-ibm-liberty-profile)

The poster states, "The project got included transitive dependencies to very old versions of cicseci library. I excluded them."

The Java Connector Architecture (JCA) level implemented in the CICS TG product has changed with the newer versions of JEE application servers now supporting the higher level of the JCA specification.  This may be the case with your upgrade.

I would suggest that you make sure you have obtained the cicseci.rar file from the /deployable/ directory where the CICS TG product is installed to make sure that your application is using the same version of the resource adapter as is supported by the CICS TG itself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me (in wildfly 12 and 21) is to add the jboss module which contains cics jars as global module in standalone-full-ha.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:5.0">
        <global-modules>
            <module name="org.jboss.cics" slot="main"/>
        </global-modules>
        .
        .
        .
        .
</subsystem>
```